# Как вывести по 3 массива строк в WORD?

Tags: delphi, ms-word

Доброго времени суток, у меня имеется n-ое количество массивов строк, мне нужно вывести по 3 массива на страница A4 ворда. Сам текст вывожу в ворд так

```
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('Ôàéë.doc');
Shellexecute(handle,'open',pansichar('Ôàéë.doc'),nil,nil,sw_restore);
```

Подскажите, будьте добры.

Comment: Размер массива известен заранее или нет?

Comment: массив динамический, размерность задается пользователем в эдит.
но я понимаю что там не нужна размерность.. просто выводить по порядку 3 массива....только не пойму как( нужен разрыв страниц в ворде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile` записывает в текстовый файл одним расширением .doc - его в ворд не превратить.

Если только разрыв страниц нужен, воспользуйтесь RichText и записывайте в rtf, для разрыва страниц используйте тег `\page`.

Про остальное можно посмотреть тут: [Формат Rich Text (RTF)](http://articles.org.ru/docum/rtf.php).

Или воспользуйтесь СОМ или OLE для доступа к ворду.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. ) С rtf получается.

Comment: Ну раз помогло галцку поставте :)